# How to solve differential equation of this type?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

So, I tried so solve the first equation, where I am looking for $p_2$, in Mathematica with next command:

```
x:=DSolve[Derivative[p2,z]==-p1*p1der/p0-8*p1/p0-8*p0der/p0^2- 
p0der*p2/p0,p2,z]
```

but i got `The function p2 appears with no arguments`. I also before that defined:

```
p0:=(1+64*(1-z))^0.5
p1:=8*(1/p0-1)
p0der:=z derivative(p0) !this is not code, just command
p1der:=z derivative(p1) !this is not code, just command
```

What should i do to solve first $p_2$, after that $p_3$ symbolic in Mathematica, i am beginner I have no idea what could be mistake and how big is it?

Comment: READ THIS FIRST!!!!! I COULD NOT POST IT BECAUSE OF EQUATIONS!!!

I am solving next two symbolic differential equations:

$$p_2'=\dfrac{-p_1p_1'+8\cdot(-p_1'-\dfrac{p_0'}{p_0})-p_0'p_2}{p_0}$$

$$p_3'=\dfrac{-p_1'p_2-p_1 p_2'-8 p_2'-8\dfrac{p_1'}{p_0}+8\dfrac{p_1 p_0'}{p_0^2}-p_0'p_3}{p_0}$$

where every variable is dependent on $z$:
$$p_0=(1+64(1-z))^{0.5}$$
$$p_1=8\cdot(\dfrac{1}{p_0}-1)$$
$$p_2=f(z)$$
$$p_3=f(z)$$

Comment: check the formating -> should be [] instead of  ()  in some cases

Comment: It is the same.

Comment: Whay do you have z_ in parenthesis in equation for p0 and p1, and after that there is only z?

Comment: Sorry, typo fixed. `p0[z_] := Sqrt[1 + 64 (1 - z)]; p1[z_] := 8 (1/p0[z] - 1); DSolve[{p2'[z] == (-p1[z] p1'[z] + 8 (-p1'[z] - p0'[z]/p0[z]) - p0'[z] p2[z])/p0[z], p3'[
z] == (-p1'[z] p2[z] - p1[z] p2'[z] - 8 p2'[z] - 8 p1'[z]/p0[z] + 8 p1[z] p0'[z]/p0[z]^2 - p0'[z] p3[z])/p0[z]}, {p2, p3}, z]`

Comment: Thanks, do you have to recommend some literature?

Comment: Mathematica Navigator, Second Edition: Mathematics, Statistics, and Graphics 2nd Edition cheap used copy or even from a library will introduce you to lots of Mathematica. Doesn't include the latest versions of Mathematica, but can show you how to define functions and how to solve systems of differential equations. The book might be available as digital file.

Answer (score 0):

```
p0[z_] := Sqrt[1 + 64 (1 - z)];
p1[z_] := 8 (1/p0[z] - 1);

eqns = {p2'[z] == (-p1[z] p1'[z] + 8 (-p1'[z] - p0'[z]/p0[z]) - p0'[z] p2[z])/p0[z], 
        p3'[z] == (-p1'[z] p2[z] - p1[z] p2'[z] - 8 p2'[z] - 8 p1'[z]/p0[z] + 
        8 p1[z] p0'[z]/p0[z]^2 - p0'[z] p3[z])/p0[z]} // Simplify;

sol = DSolve[eqns, {p2, p3}, z][[1]]

(* {p2 -> Function[{z}, 
   C[1]/Sqrt[65 - 64 z] - (4 (8 + (65 - 64 z) Log[65 - 64 z]))/(65 - 64 z)^(3/2)], 
    p3 -> Function[{z}, -((512 C[1])/((4160 - 4096 z) Sqrt[65 - 64 z])) + 
      C[2]/Sqrt[65 - 64 z] - (1/((65 - 64 z)^(5/2)))
    32 (2 (61 - 65 Sqrt[65 - 64 z] + 64 (-1 + Sqrt[65 - 64 z]) z) + (-65 + 64 z) 
         Log[65 - 64 z])]} *)
```

Verifying that the solutions satisfy the equations,

```
eqns /. sol // Simplify

(* {True, True} *)
```

The functions are real when

```
FunctionDomain[#, z] & /@ ({p2[z], p3[z]} /. sol)

(* {z < 65/64, z < 65/64} *)
```

The asymptotic values as `z -> -Infinity` are

```
Limit[#[z] /. sol, z -> -Infinity] & /@ {p2, p3}

(* {0, 0} *)
```

Setting the arbitrary constants (`C[1]` and `C[2]`) to zero and plotting

```
Plot[
 Evaluate[{p2[z], p3[z]} /. sol /. {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> 0}],
 {z, -5, 65/64},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{p2, p3}, {0.25, 0.75}]]
```

[image]